# Docusaurus 2 App trying to resolve dev dependencies

Tags: webpack, docusaurus

I have a Docusaurus 2 (using version `2.0.0-beta.9`) app where I'm using [msw](https://github.com/mswjs/msw) to write a few tests. The tests work fine the problem is that when running `npm start` (which runs `docusaurus start`), I'm seeing docusaurus trying to resolve msw dependencies, which does not make sense given I'm only referring to this dependency from test files. Is it possible to exclude the `msw` dev dependency to be processed by the underlying webpack config own by docusaurus?

Here are the logs

```
> website@0.0.0 start
> docusaurus start --host 0.0.0.0

Starting the development server...
Docusaurus website is running at: http://localhost:3000/

✖ Client
  Compiled with some errors in 6.34s

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://0.0.0.0:3000/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /Users/danielcaldas/code/my-project/website
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /index.html


Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util' in '/Users/danielcaldas/code/my-project/website/node_modules/@mswjs/interceptors/lib/interceptors/ClientRequest'
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "util": require.resolve("util/") }'
    - install 'util'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "util": false }
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/Users/danielcaldas/code/my-project/website/node_modules/@mswjs/interceptors/lib/interceptors/ClientRequest'
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
```

---

**edit**

Here's my current workaround. So a few more errors will popup along the way. I installed these fallback missing dependenings locally and editor the webpack config of docusaurus in my `node_modules` manually (I know not great...),

`node_modules/@docusaurus/core/lib/webpack/base.js` has the following content:

```js
{
    // ...
    resolve: {
        // ...
        fallback: {
          assert: require.resolve('assert/'),
          http: require.resolve('stream-http'),
          https: require.resolve('https-browserify'),
          os: require.resolve('os-browserify/browser'),
          stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
          timers: require.resolve('timers-browserify'),
          tty: require.resolve('tty-browserify'),
          zlib: require.resolve('browserify-zlib'),
        }
    },
    // ...
}
```

---

**edit 2**

It seems that docusuarus webpack was scanning under the folder `__test__`! Renaming `__test__` to `__tests__` resolved the issue, without hacking the webpack config.

---

Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend checking that you don't import `msw` in your main Docusaurus code. This is relevant only if you're using MSW for mocking in the browser. Nevertheless, a quick Cmd+F in a project's source files should be enough.

If you feel that your test files are processed by Docusaurus build, still check for suspicious imports. That `@mswjs/interceptors` dependency import does appear from somewhere, so it's likely that there's a code that imports either `msw/node` or some other module that does. Keep an eye on the imports especially if you're using a custom module structure to enable mocks (i.e. a single `mocks/index.js` file that returns the correct `setupWorker`/`setupServer` based on the importee's environment).